# Materialize dropdown and sidenav doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I'm using Materialize for my design. The dropdown and the sidenav doesn't work. The console doesn't give any errors and I did initialize the scripts after jQuery just like the materializecss.js.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- Initialize Materialize Scripts -->
    <script>$(".button-collapse").sideNav();</script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.parallax').parallax();
    });</script>
    <script>
        $(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
            hover: false
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a class="fakelink">Lite</a></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Standard</a></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Essential</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Enterprise</a></li>
  </ul>
    <nav role="navigation" class="red">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" class="brand-logo fakelink">MKHosting <span style="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;">- Easy. Fast. Secure.</span></a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="fakelink">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Hostingplans<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav" style="left:-250px;">
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Hostingplans<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button-collapse fakelink" data-activates="nav-mobile"><i class="material-icons navColorFix">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting script at the **END OF BODY ELEMENT**? It works for me.

```html
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
        hover: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the document has loaded before setting the side nav and dropdown. Just move that code inside your `document.ready` function

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- Initialize Materialize Scripts -->
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        $('.parallax').parallax();
        $(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
            hover: false
        });
    });</script>
<body>
    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a class="fakelink">Lite</a></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Standard</a></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Essential</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a class="fakelink">Enterprise</a></li>
  </ul>
    <nav role="navigation" class="red">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" class="brand-logo fakelink">MKHosting <span style="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;">- Easy. Fast. Secure.</span></a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="fakelink">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Hostingplans<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav" style="left:-250px;">
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Hostingplans<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="fakelink truncate">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button-collapse fakelink" data-activates="nav-mobile"><i class="material-icons navColorFix">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I have now tried it. It fixed my sidebar on mobile but the dropdown on desktop still doesn't work. Check for yourself: https://kohlercoding.dk/mkhosting/

Comment: It has to be something wrong with your web site, because the snippet I included works fine on desktops.

Comment: I tried to run the snippet here. Didn't work either.

Comment: It would seem my browser doesn't even see the dropdown. It's not in the "inspect element"

Comment: What browser are you using, because it works perfectly on mine.

Comment: Chrome version Version 49.0.2623.75 m

Comment: Just updated. No difference tho. Version 49.0.2623.87 m

Comment: Same version as me then... I don't know what else is wrong, sorry I could not help more.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same error. my desktop dropdown works before i add sidebar. After i added sidebar and manage to make it work, the desktop dropdown doesn't not react.

Comment: I have the same issue right now with a rails app... Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me!! You can find the entire explanation in here: http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li class="no-padding">
    <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
      <li>
        <a class="collapsible-header">Dropdown<i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></i></a>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Fourth</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Fourth</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
```